# Using Electron with Google Analytics Embed API

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, local-storage, electron

I am trying to build a desktop app using Electron with Google Analytics data. I am using Google Analytics Embed API. I get `gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy` error during authorization. I tried using 'electron-cookies' which seemed to set cookie in local storage but I still face the issue.

```
 gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID
});
```

My guess is electron uses local storage for handling cookies. Is there any workaround for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck using something like [electron-google-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-google-analytics).